# Use of Phrase "Drama Queen"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

In my writing, I am talking about a character who is a, for lack of a better word, drama queen. But because this character identifies as a male, should another character call him a "drama queen," or something else like a "drama king?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OED gives this sense and citations for the term. Notice that nothing is said of the person’s sex, and that some of the citations are for males:

> ## drama queen  *n.*
>
> a person who overreacts to a minor setback or who is prone to exaggeratedly dramatic behaviour; (also) a person who thrives on being the centre of attention.
>
> - 1923   *Washington Post* 10 Dec. 14/4   
>   If he is thwarted in his effort to enjoy them, he may either go to the dogs or the drama queens, become short-tempered, sullen, grouchy and eventually feel that, in a way he is a failure.
> - 1987   *Chicago Tribune* (Nexis) 25 June 11 e   
>   The two founding Durans still like to call their front man a ‘drama queen’.
> - 2004   J. Wilson *Diamond Girls* 6   
>   Oh for God’s sake, stop being such a drama queen! The whole world doesn’t revolve around you and your boyfriend.

This is similar to a *Queen for a Day letter*, which [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proffer_letter) has nothing to do with the defendant’s sex:

> In U.S. criminal law, a proffer letter, proffer agreement, proffer, or
> “Queen for a Day” letter is a written agreement between a prosecutor and a
> defendant or prospective witness that allows the defendant or witness to
> give the prosecutor information about an alleged crime, while limiting the
> prosecutor’s ability to use that information against him or her.
>
> The term *Queen for a Day* comes from the American radio and television
> show of the same name.

We see the same thing with the extended use of *whore* per the OED again, which demonstrates using *attention whore* in the same sense as *drama queen*, again making no distinction on the basis of sex:

> ## whore *n.*

> 4. A person regarded as willing to compromise or demean him or herself for
>    personal gain or in pursuit of a particular goal; a person regarded as
>    inconstant or promiscuous in a specified context or with regard to a
>    particular thing. Chiefly with modifying word or as the second element in
>    compounds, as in ***attention whore***, ***publicity whore***, etc.
>
>    - 2017   Ado Alsaid *North of Happy* x. 104   
>      Matt's an attention whore. The more people are there the better he'll feel.

Of course, it is perfectly **possible** to use terms like these in a belittling, derogatory sense, such as using *Princess* as a demeaning form of address for a man or boy
to imply that he is “overindulged or pampered, especially one who is arrogant, supercilious, or uncaring”.

But I don’t think *drama queen* or *attention whore* normally carries a connotation of sex-based disapproval the way calling someone *Princess* or *my lady* necessarily does.

Answer (score 1):

There is no gender conflict or issue in using 'drama queen' for a male. The term comes from (male) gay slang, in which a 'queen' is a flamboyant or effeminate gay man. The term can preceded by a specifier, e.g. a 'matzah queen' is a gay man who prefers Jewish partners, and an 'opera queen' is one who likes opera. A 'drama queen' was originally a gay man who made a big emotional fuss about trivial things, but the expression has, so to speak, come out of the closet and entered mainstream usage to mean a person of any gender or orientation who is inclined to make a fuss about everything.

Answer (score -2):

You can call him a “Crisis king”

Source: https://www.eharmony.com/dating-advice/relationship-tips/drama-queens-and-crisis-kings/

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion. Can you quote and cite references to show that this is in general use?

Comment: @AugustoPohl Can you please list the source where you found this?

Comment: There you go...